# Removing a nested list item if not found in another nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested, list-comprehension

I have two nested lists of different structures:

```
image_annotations=[['img---615.png', [[241, 429, 265, 459], [331, 340, 358, 382], [327, 293, 343, 318]]], ['img---16050.png', [[159, 74, 190, 108], [29, 57, 56, 93], [285, 310, 319, 344], [129, 247, 156, 288], [213, 285, 244, 324], [330, 151, 364, 174], [0, 373, 18, 416]]], ['img---11631.png', [[356, 25, 384, 63], [150, 29, 176, 68], [423, 50, 450, 87], [440, 466, 470, 499], [36, 41, 73, 80]]]]
```

```
keep=[[241, 429, 265, 459], [331, 340, 358, 382], [159, 74, 190, 108], [29, 57, 56, 93], [356, 25, 384, 63]]
```

I want to iterate through the larger list `image_annotations` and remove all nested lists that are not found in the smaller list `keep`. I need the structure of the larger list to remain the same (only one list per image), but the number of elements within each image list can vary. I've tried something like:

```
pick = []
for annotation in image_annotations:
    for j in annotation[1]:
        for i in keep:
            if i[0] == j[0] and i[1] == j[1] and i[2] == j[2] and i[3] == j[3]:
                pick.append(annotation)
```

but this just returns multiple copies of the same nested image lists like `keep=[['img---615.png', [[241, 429, 265, 459], [331, 340, 358, 382], [327, 293, 343, 318]]], ['img---615.png', [[241, 429, 265, 459], [331, 340, 358, 382], [327, 293, 343, 318]]]]`

My expected output is something like: 
`image_annotations=[['img---615.png', [[241, 429, 265, 459], [331, 340, 358, 382]]], ['img---16050.png', [[159, 74, 190, 108], [29, 57, 56, 93]]], ['img---11631.png', [[356, 25, 384, 63]]]]`

Ideally, I would just like to remove the elements from `image_annotations` that are not found in `keep` directly from the list instead of making a new list like above. I've been reading that list comprehensive could be the best option, but I'm just not sure how to implement something for a more complex nested list structure.

Comment: What is `pick_list`?

Answer (score 0):

You were right to consider list comprehensions. The trick is to embed a conditional inside of the List Comprehension. Here is how I did it:

```
#Variables from question example
image_annotations=[['img---615.png', [[241, 429, 265, 459], [331, 340, 358, 382], [327, 293, 343, 318]]], ['img---16050.png', [[159, 74, 190, 108], [29, 57, 56, 93], [285, 310, 319, 344], [129, 247, 156, 288], [213, 285, 244, 324], [330, 151, 364, 174], [0, 373, 18, 416]]], ['img---11631.png', [[356, 25, 384, 63], [150, 29, 176, 68], [423, 50, 450, 87], [440, 466, 470, 499], [36, 41, 73, 80]]]]
keep=[[241, 429, 265, 459], [331, 340, 358, 382], [159, 74, 190, 108], [29, 57, 56, 93], [356, 25, 384, 63]]


#Iterate through each image in the list
for image in image_annotations:
    #Only keep annotation in list if it is in keep
    image[1] = [annotation for annotation in image[1] if annotation in keep]
```

And here is the output:

```
[['img---615.png', [[241, 429, 265, 459], [331, 340, 358, 382]]], ['img---16050.png', [[159, 74, 190, 108], [29, 57, 56, 93]]], ['img---11631.png', [[356, 25, 384, 63]]]]
```

Here is what the last line is doing:

- Go through each item in image[1] and call it annotation
- If annotation is in keep, place it in the new list
- Replace the comprehended list with the new list

As a side note, list comprehensions do create another list, just without binding it to a variable name. However, since we are replacing your original list with the new one, you won't end up having to store both lists.